# PC cant even boot after BIOS clock changes

Tags: memory, bios, ramdisk

I've been having problems with my RAM and tried to overclock it to fix the issue.

I changed NorthBridge from 2400mhz to 2800mhz. When turning on, monitor does not react at all, GPU and monitor all work fine though. Fans are responding, no overheating.

I tried resetting cmos by leaving battery out and that didnt change a thing.

- 750w psu
- Gigabyte 990fxa-d3
- G.skill Ripjaws RAM 2x4gb ddr3 1333mhz
- Gtx 670
- Amd fx 8320

Answer (score 1):

The battery is there to keep the clock running. Settings on new FLASH BIOS can be stored on non-volatile flash memory inside the BIOS chips and a battery pull will not reset them.

The proper way to reset the BIOS is to program it to reset and that implies following the manual. Use a jumper cap to short out the CLR_CMOS pins.

(On your mainboard, those pins are between the ITE chip and the front panel pins)

Comment: http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/faq-page.aspx?fid=1758&pid=2844. I followed this guide for the most part, but havent a jumper cap so went with the screw driver solution. However that didnt work, I am certain I got the right pins, but it was to no avail. Should I try and get a jumper cap or is the screwdriver against the pins suffice?

Comment: Same thing, try keeping it shorted for 10 seconds or more. Also, if it's not working, take out your CPU, put it back and try again.

Comment: Ok, after taking out the battery the 2nd time for 10 minutes whilst leaving the screwdriver on the pins at the same time it's successfully reset. Cheers mate